# Self-join association with users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have models:
User has_many :orders end; 
Order belongs_to :user end;

This associations work very well but now i want that User who create order could add another Users for this order.

Edit:

In my orders/show.html.erb i have something like this

```
<%= form_for @order do |f| %>
<td>
  <%= f.select :user_id, @prac %>
</td>
```

<% end %>
I know this is wrong because i choose here id user who create order, but in this situation i have problem with define correct associations probably this is good idea? =>

```
order has_many :workes, class_name: 'User'
```

How can i achieve this functionality?

Comment: So you want to have a many-to-many relationship between users and orders? Sounds like a job for [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `has_and_belongs_to_many` association:

Create join table 'orders_users'

```
create_table :contributors_orders, :id => false do |t|
  t.integer :contributor_id
  t.integer :user_id
end
```

Add association:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :contributors, class_name: 'User'
end
```

And all should work.

Comment: I created:  create_table "orders_users", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer "order_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
  end . With this else work very well. Thx for help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can have several relations to the same class, but you probably want to differentiate them (the other Users of your order are probably not the owner). Something like:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: user
  has_many: contributors, , class_name: 'User' # need to specify else Rails will look for a "Contributor" class
end
```

This will create a one to many relation between the order and a list of Users known as "contributors":

```
owner = order.user # the initial user
contributors = order.contributors # a list of users related to this order.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Join**

You'll need to add another cog into the system - with [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) or [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) join tables

As `Martin` mentioned, you'll need to do something like this:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :orders
end

#app/models/order.rb
Class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

#orders_users table
order_id | user_id
```

This will allow you to set as many `users` per `order` as you need - allowing you to call:

```
@user = User.first
@user.orders


@order = Order.first
@order.users
```

--

Just noticed this is not `self-join`. I can refactor if you'd like it to be self-referential